# How to search on numbers in the same way like searching on strings

Tags: marklogic

In my code I have this query

```
cts.elementWordQuery(["name"], "ca*", ["wildcarded])
```

and I want to make similar query on orher field but the field type is a number.

tldr
want to method:

```
cts.elementWordQuery(["number-field"], "909*", ["wildcarded])
```

return documents with number-field property equal 9091, 9091231 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a JSON document, and it's a numeric property?

You could create a [field range index](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_14554) as string, and then:

Use `cts.fieldValueMatch()` with a wildcard to find values that start with `909`, convert those strings to `Number` and then use `cts.fieldValueQuery()` to look for those numbers:

```
const values = [];
for (const str of cts.fieldValueMatch('number-field', "909*")) { 
  values.push(Number(str)) 
}
cts.search(cts.fieldValueQuery('number-field', values))
```

Or use `cts.fieldValueMatch()` to fetch the values starting with `909*` and use them as value criteria for equality in `cts.fieldRangeQuery()`:

```
cts.search(cts.fieldRangeQuery('number-field', '=', cts.fieldValueMatch('number-field', '909*')));
```

Or use [`cts.fieldRangeQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:field-range-query) (might also need to add a `<` constraint):

```
cts.fieldRangeQuery('number-field', ">", "909")
```

Comment: A footnote on this good guidance:  in MarkLogic 10.0-8, a TDE column index and cts.columnRangeQuery() can be used instead of a range index in such cases:  https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.columnRangeQuery